# Initialization progress bar

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I made asynctask to download file from internet. Everything work fine now, but i wonder can we make a Initialization progress bar like Android market, before downloading file, It has init step. I want it shows that kind of progress bar instead of O% in mine now, Can anybody tell me how to do this?

[image]

Comment: Visit this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12119397/996493), you need to change it according to your need.